# can't see the error with a list method in python

Tags: python, list

I'am working on a exercise and I can't see where I get it wrong. I'm trying to add the indexes of the sum of two numbers to a list, but instead of getting the indexes, I'm actually getting the numbers. Here is my code, and many thanks in advance for your precious help and time.

```
a_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

target_list = []

counter = 0

for i in range(len(a_list)):
  for j in a_list:
      if i + j == 10:
          target_list.append((a_list.index(i), a_list.index(j)))
          counter += 1

print(target_list)
```

how can I do it with list comprehension.
Thank you again and again.

Comment: What purpose does the `counter` variable serve? It is also not entirely clear what output you expect since the indeces are equal to the values in your example. Pls chose more general sample data and show the expected output.

Comment: Look up `enumerate()`

Comment: you have no problem in your specific case cuz item IS index, what are you expecting?

Comment: I got it guys. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the indexes, here is an example, if you change your list to:

```
a_list = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
```

The output would be different:

```
[(0, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

what you did doesnt make any sense.. :

```
a_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

target_list = []
for i in range(len(a_list)):
  for j in a_list:
      if i + j == 10:
          target_list.append((a_list.index(i), a_list.index(j)))
>>> target_list 
[(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (5, 5), (6, 4), (7, 3), (8, 2), (9, 1)]
```

which is equal to :

```
a_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

target_list = []
for i in a_list:
  for j in a_list:
      if i + j == 10:
          target_list.append((a_list.index(i), a_list.index(j)))
>>> target_list 
[(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (5, 5), (6, 4), (7, 3), (8, 2), (9, 1)]
```

the point in python loops is that when you call `for <item> in <Iterable>:` it inserts the items to `item` and iterating each one by order, when you call `range(len(list_a))` it generates a list from 0 to the length of `a_list` , that is eaqual to `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` and this is the same thing as you list...

you could also do the following:

```
target_list = [(i,j) for j in range(10) for i in range(10) if j+i ==10]
Target_list 
>>>
[(9, 1), (8, 2), (7, 3), (6, 4), (5, 5), (4, 6), (3, 7), (2, 8), (1, 9)]
```